# Private message prefill message body

Tags: 7, privatemsg

I'm using Drupal 7 Privatemsg module.
To prefill the message body, I use the following hook but don't get anything displayed.

```
function MyModule_privatemsg_message_view_alter(&$vars) {
  module_load_include('pages.inc','privatemsg');

  $vars['message']['body'] = "<i>Dear Friend</i>,\n <strong>you rock!</strong>";
}
```

Any help ?

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to use the [Prepopulate](https://www.drupal.org/project/prepopulate) module and then customize the URL to send a privatemsg.  This works well if you are using Views to generate the links, for example.

Comment: I tried to use the URL but /message/new returns Access Denied even for admin